# Troubleshoting while realising robin round

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to create a Sheduler (for fun) but it fails. Strange is that when i'm debugging in step-over style, my programm works fine, but when i'm removing all breakpoints it freezes after printing last value. So question: why does it freezes? Second: i'm using `Thread.Resume` and `Thread.Suspend`, but they are marked as obsolete. How can i avoid it?

Code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication143
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var rrs = new RobinRoundSheduler(2, () =>
                                                {
                                                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                                                    {
                                                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i,
                                                                          Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                                                    }

                                                }) {TimeForTask = new TimeSpan(1)};
            rrs.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


    internal class RobinRoundSheduler
    {
        private readonly LinkedList<Thread> _threads;
        public TimeSpan TimeForTask { get; set; }

        public RobinRoundSheduler(int taskCount, ThreadStart start)
        {
            TimeForTask = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            _threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();
            for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
            {
                _threads.AddLast(new Thread(start));
            }
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            while (_threads.Count > 0)
            {
                var list = new List<Thread>();
                foreach (var thread in _threads)
                {
                    lock (thread)
                    {
                        if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
                            thread.Start();
                        else
                            thread.Resume();
                    }
                    thread.Join(TimeForTask);
                    lock (thread)
                    {
                        if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped || thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Aborted)
                            list.Add(thread);
                        else
                        {
                            thread.Suspend();
                        }
                    }
                }
                list.ForEach(thread => _threads.Remove(thread));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it seems having a deadlock problem due to Thread.Suspend() method but i dunno another alternative to suspend a thread withoud adding checks for ManualResetEvents in calling methods. But i want to call method knows nothing about multithreading.

Comment: Also, why are you suspending at all? (Apart from the fact that this API can almost never be used).

Comment: You are joining threads regardless of their state. You might well join a suspended thread.

Comment: The lock seems not to be used, but it also does not protect `_threads` in all cases.

Comment: How can i wait suspended thread if i'm using `thread.Resume();` before?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Before I can help you, you must answer my questions and think about the issues I found.

Comment: I said that i'm trying to do a robin-round when each thread is working for some quant of time and after control flow pass to another thread.

Comment: I understand now what you are trying to do. I recommend that you address the issues that I found and see if that fixes things.